# How to disable cookies in UIWebView ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview

I have searched and found ways to clear cookies from a `UIWebView`, but what I want to know is how to clear the cookies completely ? Guidance Needed.

Thank you.

Comment: which code you used to clear cookies?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nQFj6xT6

Answer (score 1):

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
 {
        if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:@"owner.ford.com"] || [[cookie domain] isEqualToString:@"ford.com"])
 {
    NSLog([cookie domain]);
   [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
  }
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Imp: Be sure to add the last NSUserDefaults line. Or the cookies would be back as you restart the app.**

Comment: what if the above code is run once(incl. NSUserDefaults sync) and then  the webpage is opened again?will it save the cookies again?

Comment: No it'll clean cookies completely.

Comment: can I execute this code without even loading any webpage? would it work? @gndp

Comment: one more thing I'm curious about is, how to start cookies saving again?